# Different tables for login

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a system which will have four kinds of access: administrator, vendor, proprietary and client. Each one has different fields. My doubt is:
When I create a login system, should I create a different table login, and link each login to each access?
Example:

```
Administrator->Login
Vendor->Login
Proprietary->Login
etc...
```

Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: If the roles do not fundamentally differ, use one common login table with a field to store which role, and special tables to store the role-specific information. That would be my approach.

Comment: you could use a same login table with an extra column like `status: Admin/Vendor/Proprietary` to differentiate them

Answer (score 0):

depends,

you can use sql and join the separate tables and use 1 login page.

- easy access
- easy to make
- less code
- no duplicating code

or you can use separate logins

- good security measure to prevent people from loggia in to admin accounts using brute force.

so you can use both methods and keep or the one you prefer the most

Comment: What do you mean with separate tables and only 1 login page? I didn't understand

Comment: check Tomasz's answer

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do tables like:

- users (contain login, pass, **group_id**, email etc.)
- groups (different groups of users like admin, client)
- groups_permissions (define which permissions group has)

Then you can group your users into groups and set for group special permissions to do different stuff on your website.

At the end you have only one login system and permissions depends on group which is assigned to user.

Comment: Nice Tomasz, but how would I link each user to its information? Like, how can I say that the user 35 is a client and link to the client table?

Comment: What do you mean link to the client table? If you set user 35 to group_id 1 you can get permissions which are set for this group and let user do what is allowed for this group or show specific content.

Comment: Yeah, but each role will have different fields. Example:
- Administrator: name, email, address
- Client: name, email, phone, contract_number, etc
- Vendor: name, contact, channel1, channel2.
When a user logs in I need to identify him with its information

Comment: Ok I got it. I would leave a basic user info to authenticate user and assign him to some group inside users table. Then you can create a specific tables for different types of users/groups like administrator, client, vendor which contain a more detailed data about you user and are connected with user by foreign key.